# How to create a dict from a list in the format {index : value}?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Assume this list:

```
a = [0.41   1.87  1.10  7.05]
```

I'd like to build a dict that would look as follows:

```
d = {0: 0.41, 1: 1.87, 2: 1.10, 3: 7.05}
```

There are numerous answers on SO on how to convert from a list to a dict, however I could not find one that addresses this specific need (i.e. having the key value of dict being the element's index of the list).

I can imaging there are cumbersome ways of doing this, such a using a `for` loop, getting the `a.index(i)`, appending, zipping etc but I wonder if I'm missing on a more efficient way of building this dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension for this purpose!

```
>>> d= [0.41,1.87,1.10,7.05]
>>> {index:i for index,i in enumerate(d)}
{0: 0.41, 1: 1.87, 2: 1.1, 3: 7.05}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple way:

```
>>> d = [0.41, 1.87, 1.10, 7.05]
>>> dict(enumerate(d))
{0: 0.41, 1: 1.87, 2: 1.1, 3: 7.05}
```